# Start next prompt with predefined command string in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have a function that returns a command as a string. How do I pass this command to the next prompt as a string without executing it.

**For example:**

Function `commandGenerator` returns `cd ~/some_dir/` as a string. Now I execute `commandGenerator` in my terminal:

```
> commandGenerator
> cd ~/some_dir/
                ^
                Cursor position after execution of commandGenerator.
                I can now edit the command or hit enter to execute it.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-z` option to the built-in `print` command writes text to the command buffer.

```
% print -z "cd ~/some_dir/"
% cd ~/some_dir
```

You can call this from within your `commandGenerator` function. When the function exits, the next command line will be populated with the text printed by `print -z`.